# Incorrect address being shown on delivery slip Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

My company has been having this issue for months at this point. Even our 3rd party consulting agency was unable to find the cause of this issue. We're using Odoo 15 Enterprise Edition.

Sometimes, seemingly at random, when a delivery slip is printed for a shipment for a Sales Order, the PDF that is generated and sent to the customer shows the Customer Address instead of the Delivery Address. I've yet to find a common denominator in the SOs this happens to.

I've spent the last few days Googling, messing around in one of our staging branches in the Odoo shell, and digging through the Odoo 15 repository.

This is the relevant section of the `report_deliveryslip.xml` file from the base `stock` module. I've done a `git grep` and have found a number of other modules inheriting and modifying this report, but nothing that so much as references the xpath of the delivery address.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_delivery_document">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=o._get_report_lang())" />
                <t t-set="partner" t-value="o.partner_id or (o.move_lines and o.move_lines[0].partner_id) or False"/>

                <t t-set="address">
                    <div name="div_outgoing_address">
                        <div t-if="o.should_print_delivery_address()">
                            <span><strong>Delivery Address:</strong></span>
                            <div t-field="o.move_lines[0].partner_id"
                                t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
                        </div>
```

This is a summary of some of my testing in the Odoo shell using an example SO I was provided by our shipping department, with private info redacted:

```
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: so = self.env['sale.order'].search([('name', '=', 'S12345')])           

In [2]: so.partner_id                                                           
Out[2]: res.partner(XXXXXX,)

In [3]: so.partner_shipping_id                                                  
Out[3]: res.partner(YYYYYY,)

In [4]: pick = self.env['stock.picking'].search([('origin', '=', so.name)])     

In [5]: pick.partner_id                                                         
Out[5]: res.partner(YYYYYY,)

In [6]: pick.move_lines[0].partner_id                                           
Out[6]: res.partner(YYYYYY,)

In [7]: print(pick.move_lines[0].partner_id._display_address())                 
Correct Contact Name
123 Correct Street
Unit 456
New York NY 01234
United States

In [8]: pick.should_print_delivery_address()                                    
Out[8]: True

In [9]:
```

A couple of final notes. I tried the `_render_qweb_html` method as well as the `_render_qweb_pdf` and `_render_qweb_text` methods from the Odoo shell in order to manually generate new copies of the delivery slip, and all three had "Customer Address" with the incorrect address shown instead of "Delivery Address" and the correct address.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding the solution. In the `report_deliveryslip.xml` file, there is the following tag:

```xml
<t t-set="address">
    <div name="div_outgoing_address">
        <div t-if="o.should_print_delivery_address()">
            <span><strong>Delivery Address:</strong></span>
            <div t-field="o.move_lines[0].partner_id"
                t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
        </div>
        <div t-elif="o.picking_type_id.code != 'internal' and o.picking_type_id.warehouse_id.partner_id">
            <span><strong>Warehouse Address:</strong></span>
            <div t-field="o.picking_type_id.warehouse_id.partner_id"
                t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

I had originally thought this was what was generating the HTML that then was used to generate the PDF. However, this `<t>` tag is for the "outgoing" address, which counterintuitively is where the shipment is "outgoing" FROM, aka our facility's address. This next XML snippet is where the customer's address is pulled in and the HTML is generated for it.

```xml
<t t-set="information_block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7" name="div_incoming_address">
            <t t-set="show_partner" t-value="False" />
            <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='incoming' and partner">
                <span><strong>Vendor Address:</strong></span>
                <t t-set="show_partner" t-value="True" />
            </div>
            <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='outgoing' and partner and partner != partner.commercial_partner_id">
                <span><strong>Customer Address:</strong></span>
                <t t-set="show_partner" t-value="True" />
            </div>
            <div t-if="show_partner" name="partner_header">
                <div t-field="partner.commercial_partner_id"
                    t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
                <p t-if="partner.sudo().commercial_partner_id.vat"><t t-esc="o.company_id.country_id.vat_label or 'Tax ID'"/>: <span t-field="partner.sudo().commercial_partner_id.vat"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

The following line is what finally ended up being the answer.

```xml
<div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='outgoing' and partner and partner != partner.commercial_partner_id">
```

I did some further testing in the Odoo shell with the `res.partner` record assigned to one of our shipments that had the shipping address issue, and found out that running `partner == partner.commercial_partner_id` returned `False`. Initially when I saw this, I assumed we maybe had some records with their `commercial_partner_id` set incorrectly. I then found the field definition for `commercial_partner_id` in the `res.partner` model, which is shown below.

```py
commercial_partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Commercial Entity',
                                        compute='_compute_commercial_partner', recursive=True,
                                        store=True, index=True)
```

I then went and found the compute method, which is shown below.

```py
@api.depends('is_company', 'parent_id.commercial_partner_id')
def _compute_commercial_partner(self):
    for partner in self:
        if partner.is_company or not partner.parent_id:
            partner.commercial_partner_id = partner
        else:
            partner.commercial_partner_id = partner.parent_id.commercial_partner_id
```

Some final testing (and sanity checking against 5 other shipments with the same delivery address issue) in the Odoo shell revealed the reason these shipments had the incorrect delivery addresses generated on the delivery slips. It's because the `res.partner` records for the delivery addresses are not marked as "Company" type records, and instead they are listed as "Individual" records, with the main "Company" records being set as their parents.

We've yet to determine a specific solution for this issue. Changing the delivery address `res.partner` records to the "Company" type would break the contact hierarchy, and changing the address of the parent company record could cause potential issues in the future.